# Selenium Python - GetAttr

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, getattr

I'm trying to do an automation web test with Selenium Python. Where I could read the xpath of an WebElement and/or the method I want to do with it for example send_keys() from an Excel file.

I managed to make the code works, but problem is the method click() doesn't work. Nothing happens.

```
 try:
                ActualValue = dv.find_element_by_xpath(f1)
                if f3 != '':
                    getattr(ActualValue, f2)(f3)
                else:
                    getattr(ActualValue, f2)
```

In the above code, I splited the strings from Excel file to 3 parts, f1 is the path to get to the WebElement, f2 is the Method/ Attribute, f3 is the Parameter.

The code works fine for other methods, just the click() one doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is `getattr`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 0):

`click()` is a method with parameter `self`. You need to send this parameter as well

```
getattr(ActualValue, 'click')()
```

Comment: Right!!! Works like a charm haha. Thank you. How could I forget it!